# Remove head from a quarter turn tap with no screw

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I'm trying to install a tap (*see photograph*), but the tap head is getting in the way due to restricted space. I'd like to try and remove the head so that I can install the body and then reinstall the head later.

However I am unable to figure out how to remove the head. There are no grub screws at all.

Any thoughts?

[image: Tap]

[Product page](https://newarc.com.tr/tr/urun/armaturler/musluklar/musluklar-minart-ara-musluk-191131/)

Comment: you sure the lever itself isn't a grub screw? Didn't it come with an explosion diagram or something - not just the dimension diagram you linked to?

Comment: The lever and tap head appear to be one solid part. There is no extra documentation in the box.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/293889). Maybe, instead of asking how to disassemble something that appears to not be designed to be end-user disassembled, you provide a picture of the _actual_ installation you've got going on, showing what is in the way of what (include whatever tools/pieces/etc that are being interfered with) and ask how to resolve _that_ problem.  Disassembly of the tap itself is _highly likely_ to _not_ be the correct solution, or the mfgr would have included instructions to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the "newarc" logo disc is in fact a separate part which can be prised off, revealing a center-bore screw head beneath.  See if that's possible.
A more remote possibility is that the entire handle can be prised vertically, i.e. it's a strong press-fit onto the internal valve tubing.

Comment: If it's a "strong press fit" as you suggest (and I suspect you may be right), attempting to remove it could damage the handle/cap assembly. _If_ one were to remove it without significant damage, attempting to press it back on (once the whole thing is installed on the wall) could cause significant additional damage. It may be possible, but I'm not sure I would recommend it.

Comment: I suspect as well that one of these is the correct answer. Similar same-manufacturer taps show a setscrew axial with the main shaft, with an obviously-removeable handle escutcheon. If the handle on this one is really one piece, it is most likely a strong press-fit. Another approach would be to buy an identical Minart 19311 tap (Amazon in Turkey has these taps for ~100 Turkish Lira) and disassemble it on the bench to see what's up. A new one might even come with instructions.